# In Oblivion how does Julia get pregnant?

Tags: plot-explanation, oblivion

At the end of the [film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1483013/), after [Beech](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0380361/?ref_=tt_cl_t2) and [Tech 49 Jack](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0380358/?ref_=tt_cl_t1) sacrifice themselves and destroy the ship [Julia](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0380359/?ref_=tt_cl_t3) is then seen with a child (who looks about 3 years old). She is then re-introduced to Tech 52 Jack and the way I perceived this was Tech 49 Jacks child but how is this possible if he is dead and there was nothing more than a kiss shown to happen between them?

Comment: I'm a firm believer that parents should be the ones explaining how babies are made.

Comment: Didn't Julia spend a night in the cabin with Tech 49...?

Comment: @AidanO You're right I forgot about that. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it for you

Comment: Don't happen to know the answer to my other question about this film by any chance? http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11086/in-oblivion-how-can-jack-and-victoria-live-in-the-sky

Comment: I think the original Jack must have known they were expecting a daughter. In the end voice-over from 52 he refers to a daughter "I wonder if you see me when you look at her".

Comment: I think Mhz must have it right. The voiceover reference to the daughter at the end (the voiceover is intended to be Tech 52) must mean that the original Jack knew she was pregnant.
QED she was pregnant before the mission and in Delta sleep.

Comment: How did this slip my mind? It seemed so seamless at the time I watched it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "Jack" who found Julia and saved her from her ship wreckage, slept with her at the hideaway, this is when she got pregnant.  A year or two later, the other "Jack" was found and brought to her. All of the "Jacks", had the same memory of Julia...thus, they still loved each other.

Answer (score 2):

Julia was in Delta sleep for 60 years. She might have been pregnant before Delta sleep. Delta sleep apparently halts aging and embryonic growth, until the person wakes up again.